# CSS Bootstrap stop hover border on active item

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How do I stop a border being applied twice... once for the active item and once on the hover?

I've tried using `.navbar a:not(.active):hover` but it doesn't work. I've also tried giving all navbar items a bottom border that is of the required thickness but of the background colour and changing the colour on the hover.

The desired effect is that the active item is in bold and has a white `bottom-border`, whilst the item the mouse is over also has a white `bottom-border` (shown in red in the image) but isn't in bold (as both colours will be white I'm not bothered about which one 'wins'). But my problem is when the mouse is over the active item the `bottom-border` is added twice.

[image: Code and effect.]

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). An image of CSS is not code....

Comment: An element cannot have two borders so there are obviously two elements here....probably an `li` and an anchor `a`...Decide which gets the border and adjust your CSS accordingly.

Comment: @Paulie_D: I understand an element can not have two borders, I have a `li` containing an `Html.ActionLink` would the later count as an anchor `a`?

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely due to a border being applied to 2 different elements.

I made you a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/msdku8mj/) to understand the issue.

As you can see all is working correctly because both the .active class and the :hover pseudo class are referred to the ul > li.

```
ul > li.active{
  border-bottom:3px solid red;
}

ul > li:hover{
  border-bottom: 3px solid yellow;
}
```

If you try for example to change the :hover to ul > li > a you see the double border.

```
ul > li.active{
  border-bottom:3px solid red;
}

ul > li > a:hover{
  border-bottom: 3px solid yellow; /* double border */
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I thought it would be something along that line. I've made my own [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6Lp9xpou/) (might not work it's my first attempt). But as you can see the hover background colour is a light grey, I want it to be the same as the background (so it doesn't appear to be anything) but can't get it to work.

Comment: Here you are the working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6Lp9xpou/2/)  without the grey background. It was caused by the background rule in `.nav > li > a:hover` that needed to be overwritten. You can see it commented in the last lines of the CSS section in the fiddle. Vote my previous answer as correct if solved your issue. Thank you

Comment: I need to play with this a bit more, it works okay in jsfiddle but it in my project I still get the double border :(